# Is $\hom(V,W)$ also a "dual" of something?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, tensor-products, dual-spaces

In linear algebra, a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ has a dual vector space $V^*$, and it's said somewhere that $V^*$ comes "for free". By "for free", I guess it means that there is nothing else to be required other then $V$ & $ \mathbb{F}$ for obtaining $V^*$.

In the similar setting, it seems that given two vector spaces $V, W$ over $\mathbb{F}$, the vector space $\hom(V,W)$ also kind of "comes for free".

I am curious on what separates $V^*$ (i.e., $\hom(V,\mathbb{F})$) apart from $\hom(V,W)$ to give it a dedicated name "dual space" (besides $\dim V=\dim V^*$)?

Or, as the title shows, is $\hom(V,W)$ a dual space of something else? If not, why?

Comment: If $V, W$ are finite-dimensional, then $\operatorname{hom}(V, W) \cong V^*\otimes W. $

Comment: And $ V^* \otimes F \cong V^* $ (indeed, $U \otimes F \cong F$ for any $F$–vector space $U$), so $V^*$ is the unique extra object you need to build any of the spaces $F$–linear maps out of $V$ (i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ for any other $F$–vector space $W$). (Some of this requiring finite-dimensional.)

Comment: @Chappers Did you mean $U\otimes F\cong U$?

Comment: Whoops, yes, I certainly did!

Answer (score 9):

First a brief remark about your first paragraph: The data specifying the vector space structure of a vector space $V$ includes the underlying field, so in that sense $V^*$ can be defined just using the vector space $V$.

Now, expanding Douglas' remark in the comments, for f.d. vector spaces $V, W$ over a given field $\Bbb F$ we have
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Hom}(V, W)^* \cong (W \otimes V^*)^* \cong W^* \otimes V^{**} \cong W^* \otimes V \cong V \otimes W^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}(W, V)} .$$

We can describe this isomorphism explicitly: Define the linear map $$\Phi : \operatorname{Hom}(W, V) \to \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)^*$$ by
$$\Phi(T)(S) := \operatorname{tr}(S \circ T) .$$
By definition if $T \in \ker \Phi$, then $\operatorname{tr}(S \circ T) = 0$ for all $S \in \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$, so $T = 0$, and thus $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

In the case $W = \Bbb F$, $S \in \operatorname{Hom}(V, \Bbb F) = V^*$ and $T \in \operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb F, V)$, but we can naturally identify this latter space with $V$ via the map $f \mapsto f(1)$, so $\Phi(S)(T)$ is a map $\Bbb F \to \Bbb F$, which we can identify with its trace, and hence under these canonical identifications $\Phi$ specializes to the pairing $V^* \times V \to \Bbb F$, $(\alpha, X) \mapsto \alpha(X)$, defining the dual $V^*$ of a vector space $V$.